Using wine for .bat file
I am trying to use Windows Subsystem for Android on Wine but a version with Magisk built into it. In the documentation it requires you to:


Extract the .7z archive using 7-zip (recommended) and rename the extracted folder to WSA.....
4. Open the WSA folder and double-click on Run.bat



I am using the latest Wine with WineGUI. My system meets the hardware requirements because I used it when I was on Windows. Wine is using Windows 10 64bit so I chose the correct build from the releases of WSA but every time I run the Run.bat file, it begins to run the file and then the command prompt just disappears and nothing installs:
Running command with Wine GUI
As the documentation says:

You can NOT delete the WSA installation folder.
What Add-AppxPackage -Register .\AppxManifest.xml does is to register an appx package with some existing unpackaged files,
so you need to keep them as long as you want to use WSA.

This means the files must be used every time I run the app. I am just not sure how to even get it to install on Wine.

Wine is not a full edition of Windows and may well not support platform level features required by specialised software. You may well "meet the hardware requirements" but WINE is not Windows 10 and may not have everything required by WSA or random github installers. WINE works best with mature applications using tried and trusted methods. Rather than WINE you may be better off running Windows 10 in a VM.

Look at the .bat file and see if you can modify and perform individual commands in Terminal, then write a bash script for it. BTW, Window version of 7-Zip runs very well in wine. The only oddity is that the directory structure looks a but different than on Windows.

Thanks guys but I've given up on it I wasted a whole day trying to figure it out just going to use Waydroid on Linux instead :(
